# Am I charged for bandwidth between an AppEngine app and Compute Engine instance?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I have a server running on a Compute Engine instance that makes requests to an AppEngine application (in the same API project, FWIW).  Am I charged "outgoing bandwidth" on the data flowing out of the AppEngine app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  If there's a GCE instance and a GAE app talking to one another you're not billed for [incoming or outgoing bandwidth for GCE](https://developers.google.com/compute/pricing), but you are billed for [outgoing bandwidth from GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing#cost_resource).

Comment: uow, this will be very expensive